Expo deployment error on iOS: "Run fastlane" step failed with unknown error
I am trying to build and deploy a React Native application. I've been successful in doing so for quite some time, but after hiring on a contractor to help out recently, I have been completely unable to build out the project, and unable to debug the exact solution to this problem.
When I run npx eas build --profile production -p ios , I get the following error:
iOS Build Failed log
Run fastlane error log
Upon further inspecting the Xcode Logs, the fatal error appears here:
/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@shopify/react-native-skia/cpp/skia/include/core/SkStream.h:11:10: fatal error: 'include/core/SkData.h' file not found
#include "include/core/SkData.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

CompileC /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PET-ezkkazzwyhcqmsbskripscllyesr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/PET/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/react-native-skia.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SkiaPictureViewManager.o /Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@shopify/react-native-skia/ios/RNSkia-iOS/SkiaPictureViewManager.mm normal arm64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'react-native-skia' from project 'Pods')
    cd /Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/Pods
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c++ -ivfsstatcache /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDKStatCaches.noindex/iphoneos17.4-21E210-99a79c02cfa501706f5b564e46d84afe.sdkstatcache -fmessage-length\=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit\=0 -fno-color-diagnostics -fmodules-prune-interval\=86400 -fmodules-prune-after\=345600 -fbuild-session-file\=/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror\=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror\=return-type -Wdocumentation -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror\=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Wno-objc-interface-ivars -Werror\=objc-root-class -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wimplicit-retain-self -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wdeprecated-implementations -Wno-c++11-extensions -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wmove -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wrange-loop-analysis -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -Wunguarded-availability @/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PET-ezkkazzwyhcqmsbskripscllyesr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/PET/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/react-native-skia.build/Objects-normal/arm64/af3fcb34312c57c0f52879cdce924b91-common-args.resp -include /Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/react-native-skia/react-native-skia-prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PET-ezkkazzwyhcqmsbskripscllyesr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/PET/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/react-native-skia.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SkiaPictureViewManager.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PET-ezkkazzwyhcqmsbskripscllyesr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/PET/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/react-native-skia.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SkiaPictureViewManager.dia -c /Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@shopify/react-native-skia/ios/RNSkia-iOS/SkiaPictureViewManager.mm -o /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PET-ezkkazzwyhcqmsbskripscllyesr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/PET/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/react-native-skia.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SkiaPictureViewManager.o

What do I need to do to sort this out and get my builds back up and out there?
I've seen various other ambiguous "Fastlane" errors posted here with no consistent solutions, but have not yet seen one addressing this particular issue.
